# Python AttributeError NoneType 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Trying to make a python script that can scrape from pastebin's RAW Paste Data section of the page on saved pastebin outputs. But I'm running into an issue with Python Attribute Error about NoneType has no object attribute 'text', I'm using the libraries from BeautifulSoup in my project. I tried to install `spider-egg` with `pip install` so I could use that also, but there was issues downloading the package from the server.

I need to be able to grab different multiple lines from the RAW Paste Data section and the print them back out to me.

```
first_string = raw_box.text.strip()
second_string = raw_box2.text.strip()
```

from the pastebin page I have the class element names for the RAW Paste Data section which is;

```
<textarea id="paste_code" class="paste_code" name="paste_code" onkeydown="return catchTab(this,event)">
```

taking the class name `paste_code` I then have this

```
raw_box = soup.find('first_string ', attrs={'class': 'paste_code'})
raw_box2 = soup.find('second_string ', attrs={'class': 'paste_code'})
```

I thought that should of been it, but apparently not, because I get the error I mentioned before. After parsing the data that has been stripped I need to be able to redirect that into a file after printing what it got. I also want to try make this python3 compatible, but that would take a little more work I think, since there's a lot of differences between python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2.

Comment: That specific error tells you that one of your `raw_box` variables is `None`, which means that the string you're trying to `find` is not present (at least, not in the kind of element you're searching). It may be that not finding any matches is an expected situation, in which case you should probably put an `if raw_box is None` check and handle that case differently. If it is unexpected, you need to investigate further to find out why you're not getting the results you expect (and we can't really help with the limited information you've provided).

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should help to get you started:

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/hGeHMBQf')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
raw = soup.find('textarea', id='paste_code').text

print raw
```

Which for this example should display:

```
hello world
```